# Change the id of an object in Plone when not published

Tags: plone

In our use case, if the title of an unpublished object is modified we would like to change its id according with the new title.

We try to accomplish it using a simple subscriber without success:

ZCML:

```xml
<configure
    xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
    xmlns:zcml="http://namespaces.zope.org/zcml">

  <subscriber
      for="DummyContentType
           zope.lifecycleevent.IObjectModifiedEvent"
      handler=".subscriber.update_id"
      />

</configure>
```

Python:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from plone import api
from plone.i18n.normalizer.interfaces import IIDNormalizer
from zope.component import queryUtility


def update_id(obj, event):
    state = api.content.get_state(obj)
    if state != 'private':
        return
    util = queryUtility(IIDNormalizer)
    new_id = util.normalize(obj.Title())
    api.content.rename(obj=obj, new_id=new_id, safe_id=True)
    obj.reindexObject()
```

When this code run we get an **ResourceLockedError** exception

Comment: which event are you subscribing to?

Comment: BTW what you are doing may break you site. Consider 10000 objects below the modified content (In case it is folderish). If not you finde :-)

Comment: @gforcada zope.lifecycleevent.IObjectModifiedEvent